# NSTimer - how to delay in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I have a problem with delaying computer's move in a game.

I've found some solutions but they don't work in my case, e.g.

```
var delay = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4, target: self, selector: nil, userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

I tried to use this with function `fire` but also to no effects.

What other possibilities there are?

Comment: You clearly don't understand what an NSTimer does. You need to have a selector, and have some code in  that method you want to run when the timer fires. A timer without a selector doesn't do anything.

Comment: This answer is what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/3810673

Comment: thank you very much! I didn't understand the selector because I don't get it why it should be in apostrophe. I put there my func and eveything works great.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

**Swift 3**

With GCD:

```
let delayInSeconds = 4.0
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delayInSeconds) {

    // here code perfomed with delay

}
```

or with a timer:

```
func myPerformeCode() {

   // here code to perform
}
let myTimer : Timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4, target: self, selector: #selector(self.myPerformeCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

**Swift 2**

With GCD:

```
let seconds = 4.0
let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)  // nanoseconds per seconds
let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

   // here code perfomed with delay

})
```

or with a timer:

```
func myPerformeCode(timer : NSTimer) {

   // here code to perform
}
let myTimer : NSTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4, target: self, selector: Selector("myPerformeCode:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Comment: that's a great solution without making any extra methods. I didn't think about using parameters to my main method, thank you!

Comment: Wanted to upvote, only to discover I already did in the past :)

Answer (score 7):

**With Swift 4.2**

With `Timer` You can avoid using a selector, using a closure instead:

```
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false) { (nil) in
        // Your code here
    }
```

Keep in mind that `Timer` is toll-free bridged with `CFRunLoopTimer`, and that run loops and GCD are two completely different approaches....   e

Answer (score 2):

In swift we can delay by using `Dispatch_after.`

SWift 3.0 :-

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+4.0) {

        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using Grand Central Dispatch?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html

Valfer has shown you how