# Swift iOS- How to hide label then make it appear after a certain time period

Tags: ios, swift, timer, viewdidappear, hiddenfield

I have a label that gets hidden when a button is pressed. After a certain time period like 60 secs I want the label to reappear. I'd assume I do that in viewDidAppear, How would i do that?

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
       //after 60 secs myLabel should reappear
       //self.myLabel.isHidden = false
    }


@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton){
       self.myLabel.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: did you even try to google that?

Comment: Please Google before you ask :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990085/nstimer-how-to-delay-in-swift

Comment: @ Steffen Lund Andersen It didn;t cross my mind but your right I should've just googled it. Thanks as it's the answer i was looking for :)!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton){
    self.myLabel.isHidden = true
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 60) {
        self.myLabel.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by scheduling a timer:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        if !myLabel.isHidden {
            myLabel.isHidden = true
            Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 15.0, target: self, selector: #selector(showLabel), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        }
    }

    func showLabel() {
        myLabel.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: I up voted your answer but I already accepted Max's. Thanks! :)

Comment: Be aware of each time you are tapping the button you'll add another timer schedule.

Comment: @AhmadF Thanks! I updated the answer by cheking `myLabel.isHidden`